# Computed Properties aren't updating as expected after models load. Am I using them incorrectly?

Tags: ember.js

I've got a monthly calendar display, and I'm trying to list all events that are scheduled for the month. It's not working at boot -- no events appear. But if I click 'next' (not shown) to switch months, the filtering works. (And if I switch back to the original month, events will appear as desired.)

Suspect there's an error in my use of computed properties.

Question: how can I get the monthEvents computed property to fire after the Events have loaded?

I know it's firing once at boot, but that no events are loaded yet. (I've done:

```
console.log(this.get('controllers.events.content.get('length'))
```

from within monthEvents, and the count is initially zero.

My hope is that it would refire after the Events successfully loaded. (I'm using Ember Data, and I'm loading the events in the ApplicationRoute -- is that a mistake?)

Here's the MonthsEventsController:

```
App.MonthEventsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['events', 'month'],
  monthEvents: function() {
    var currentMonth = this.get('controllers.month.content');
    return this.get('controllers.events.content').filter(function(event) { 
      return currentMonth.doesContainDate(event.get('startTime'));
    });
  }.property('controllers.events@each.startTime', 'controllers.month.content')
});
```

And the ApplicationRoute which loads the events:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('events').set('content', App.Event.find());
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Is there someplace specific in my code where I should force the Run Loop to execute? (I've tried tossing around Ember.run.sync(), at various random points in the code, no luck yet.) Or do I somehow need to wire up the computed property differently?

Thanks

Comment: You've got a typo, it should be `controllers.events.@each.startTime`

Comment: um, uh, yeah. that was it. deep shame. many thanks.